# Como puedo descargar los archivos de diferencia que hay entre dos ramas?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Necesito saber si hay alguna forma de descargar los archivos de diferencia entre dos ramas. Idealmente que se descarguen con sus carpetas correspondientes

Answer (score 0):

@Carlos haciendo un `git pull origin rama` lo que haces es descargarte los archivos diferentes de otra rama a la que estas. Automáticamente se te realiza el merge con el código que estas.

Por ejemplo si trabajo en rama1 y termino lo que estoy realizando y después creo la rama2 y me pongo a trabajar en ella para continuar el código. Mi árbol de ramas es que la rama2 tiene el código mas avanzado que la rama1. Pero me dicen que toce algo de código en rama1 como rama2 deriva de rama1 tendré que pasarle esos cambios a rama2.

Entonces lo que hago es el `git pull origin rama1` estando en rama2 para traerme los cambios de rama1 a la 2.

Espero que te haya respondido tu pregunta.